# Having issues subclassing CCSprite. What did I miss?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I've recently picked up app writing as a hobby and I've run into a problem with my first app.  My first app attempt is fairly simple...a domino game.  I started out using an NSObject class to describe each tile, but I think I've decided that CCSprite is easier for me at the moment.

The first step was creating an NSArray of all the tiles and then shuffling them.  This is where I'm getting stuck....

**Domino.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface Domino : CCSprite {
    int int_leading;
    int int_trailing;
    int int_suitrank;
    int int_trickvalue;

    NSString *str_tilename;
    NSString *str_mirrortilename;

}


@property  int int_leading,int_trailing, int_suitrank, int_trickvalue; 

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *str_tilename;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *str_mirrortilename;

-(void) print;
-(void) setTileName: (NSString *) theTileName;
-(void) setMirrorName: (NSString *) theMirrorName;
-(NSString *) str_tilename;
-(NSString *) str_mirrortilename;

@end
```

**Domino.m**

```
@implementation Domino

@synthesize int_leading,int_trailing, int_suitrank, int_trickvalue, str_tilename, str_mirrortilename;
//@synthesize char_tilename, char_mirrortilename;

-(void) print     { 
    NSLog (@"%i/%i", int_leading, int_trailing);}

-(void) setTileName: (NSString *) theTileName;
{
    str_tilename=[[NSString alloc] initWithString: theTileName];
}

-(void) setMirrorName: (NSString *) theMirrorName;
{
    str_mirrortilename=[[NSString alloc] initWithString: theMirrorName];
}

-(NSString *) str_tilename
{
    return str_tilename;
}

-(NSString *) str_mirrortilename
{
    return str_mirrortilename;
}
@end
```

**helloworld.m**

```
// Import the interfaces
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"
#import "Domino.h"
// HelloWorldLayer implementation
@implementation HelloWorldLayer
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        //NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Domino *d00 =[[Domino alloc] init];
        NSString *TileName= @"0-0.png";
        NSString *MirrorName= @"0-0.png";
        [d00 setTileName: TileName];
        [d00 setMirrorName: MirrorName];
        d00.int_leading=0;
        d00.int_trailing=0;
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
        movableSprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //build initial array of tiles
        NSArray *uniquetiles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        d00,d01,d02,d03,d04,d05,d06, 
            d11,d12,d13,d14,d15,d16,     
                d22,d23,d24,d25,d26,
                    d33,d34,d35,d36,
                        d44,d45,d46,
                            d55,d56,
                                d66,
        nil];  

 //shuffle integer array representing tile index number
    int tile[28];    // array of tile row ids;

        for (int i=0; i<28; i++) {
            tile[i] = i;  // fill the array in order
        }

        for (int i=0; i<(27-1); i++) {
            int r = i + (arc4random() % (27-i)); // Random remaining position.
            int temp = tile[i]; tile[i] = tile[r]; tile[r] = temp;

        }
        int i=30;
        Domino *sprite =[[Domino alloc] init];
        for(int h = 1; h < 8; ++h) {

            for(int w=0;w<4; ++w){

                i=tile[(h-1)*4+(w)];        
                NSString *name=[[uniquetiles objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"str_tilename"];
                CGPoint spriteOffset = ccp(100+60*w, 45+25*h);
NSLog(@" client Id : %@",[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:name]);

                sprite=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:name];
                sprite.scale=.50;
                sprite.int_leading=1; //program fails here
```

When I try to set the value of the tile, I end up getting a "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCSprite setInt_leading:]"  What am I doing different here than what I just did before when I defined d00?

Comment: Try commenting out this line sprite=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:name];.  Does your program still crash?

Comment: Yes, that was a part of the problem.  The biggest issue was that I was trying to pass the domino ccsprite subclass properties into a ccsprite class.  Commenting that line out was what made me realize what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for one thing that is bothering me, you never actually set up a image for the sprite to use.  I see you setting up the strings to load an image but I don't see you loading the image.

More importantly I am guessing is that you did not set any rules for your properties.  I expect making:

```
@property  int int_leading,int_trailing, int_suitrank, int_trickvalue;
```

Into:

```
@property  (nonatomic, retain) int int_leading,int_trailing, int_suitrank, int_trickvalue;
```

would fix your problem.  (or assign)

Comment: Wow, a good night's sleep does a lot of good.  I was way overcomplicating things.  I was using Ray's example for moving sprites around and was trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.  My thought on not setting up the image was that it would initially need to be blank and then I would use the str_tilename to replace the blank face once the tile is selected.  Why I was making a separate object called "sprite" is beyond me.  I'm sure it made sense at the time...

Comment: Appreciate the help.  I've been struggling with objective-c/cocos2d learning curve for a few weeks now on my own.  Certainly is nice to see a little progress for a change.

Comment: Yeah I can understand that.  I have learned Objective-C, Cocos2D, and Box2D while programming my current game.